# Not able to display images in blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have Image in public/storage/images directory. I am accessing them with the asset()

```
 <img src="{{ asset('/storage/images/img_1.jpg') }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
```

But they are not getting displayed.

Comment: Show me your store method.

Comment: [Have you checked the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk)? Why are you using an absolute path (`/storage`), when the docs show a relative path? Have you created the symlink as described in the docs? `not getting displayed` - does that mean 404?  Or some permissions error?  C'mon, try a bit harder, there is a lot you can investigate! :-)

Comment: just f12 or inspect the element of image .. make sure the path sets correctly or not...

Answer (score 0):

have you created the symbolic link? If not you can do so by running the command below.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

For further information, do refer to the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following, if your image in the `asset` folder.

```
<img src="{{ asset('/images/img_1.jpg') }}" alt="Image" class="img-fluid">
```